# How to static_assert each data member of a C++ lambda?

Tags: c++, lambda, member, static-assert

How can one call `static_assert` for each data member of any given C++ lambda?

What I'm trying to do is roll my own memcpy-able `std::function` and have realized that any lambdas must have trivially copyable data members. I'd like to put some assertions in place for this.

Example:

```
template<typename T> struct has_trivial_copy {enum {value = false};};
template<> struct has_trivial_copy<int> {enum {value = true};};

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    std::string str;

    auto lambda1 = [i] {
        // static_assert(has_trivial_copy<each data member...>::value); // okay
    };

    auto lambda2 = [i, str] {
        // static_assert(has_trivial_copy<each data member...>::value); // fail
    };
}
```

Comment: There is nothing built-in into C++ for that. It is up to you to call `static_assert` for whatever you want it to be called.

Comment: "_What I'm trying to do is roll my own memcpy-able std::function and have realized that any lambdas must have trivially copyable data members._": Why do you need that? You only need to check `std::is_trivially_copyable` on the lambda type itself.

Comment: You cannot implement `std::is_trivially_copyable` in user C++ by the way. That requires magic compiler support. And having a trivial copy operation is not the same as being trivially copyable, which is what is required for memcpy.

Comment: if `std::is_trivially_copyable_v<decltype(lambda2)>` is `true` then the lambda does not have members that are not trivially copyable

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `std::is_trivially_copyable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not possible to call `static_assert` for every member of a lambda, it is possible to use `std::is_trivially_copyable` on any given lambda to assert that it is trivially copyable.

I've added the following `static_assert` to my custom `std::function` and it works nicely to show me all the places where I'm using non-trivially copyable data members in lambdas:

```
template <typename Functor, typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct FunctorHolder
{
    FunctorHolder (Functor func) : f (func)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<Functor>::value);
    }

    Functor f;
};
```

Comment: There is a difference between the type itself being trivially-copyable and all of its static members being trivially-copyable. In particular, it is up to the compiler to decide whether any given lambda is trivially-copyable, see https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#closure-3.2. But since you intent to memcpy the lambda, not its members, checking the property of the lambda is the only correct thing to do anyway.

Comment: @user17732522 "...and all of its static members being ..." -> non-static members